# How to add Cordova-SQLitePlugin?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

In github [official(?) page,](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) , says `cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage`

And in some other posts, it says, `cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.git`

What is the right way to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the github link is the official Cordova repo.

The official list of Github repos for Cordova are here on [Apache's Github](https://github.com/apache?page=1&query=cordova&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

According to this, there is no official Cordova plugin for SQLite. 
So you can install one of your choice listed in the [Cordova official plugin registry](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/search?search=sqlite), or one you can find elsewhere if it seems good enough for your needs.

You can also use the one you specified, using `cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.git`